# Empty set question

Tags: discrete-mathematics

> $$ | \{ \{ \} \} | = 0. $$

Is this true or false?

Comment: The set $\{\{\}\}$ has exactly one element, namely $\{\}$, so its cardinality is $1$.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's not. That set contains exactly one element: {}, so its cardinality is 1, not 0.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.